# How can I get a PHP value from an HTML form?

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form as follows:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" " method="post">
<input name="username" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary"/><br/>
</form>
```

I want that the user of this form enters data in the input box. Then I would like this data to be the value of a PHP string - e.g. `$username = "MY_NAME";` where `MY_NAME` is the value of the HTML form entered by the user.

If the input by the user in the input box is e.g. `"STACKOVERFLOW"` I want the PHP string to be `$username = "STACKOVERFLOW";`

Comment: add a name to your submit button and first check if the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the form submits, you need to get the values from the [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array

You can do `print_r($_POST)` to see everything it contains (all of the form fields) and reference them individually as well.

Username will be `$_POST['username']`

I recommend reading a tutorial on working with forms and PHP... [here's a good one](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php/)

Since you're obviously a beginner I'll help you out a bit more:

Give your submit button a name:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary"/><br/>
</form>
```

Because `action` is blank, it will POST to the current page. At the top of your file, you can check to see if the form was submitted by checking if `$_POST['submit']` is set (I gave your submit button that name).

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // form submitted, now we can look at the data that came through
    // the value inside the brackets comes from the name attribute of the input field. (just like submit above)
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    // Now you can do whatever with this variable.
}
// close the PHP tag and your HTML will be below
```

Comment: so is it something kli this please? $username = ($_POST['username']);

Comment: Yes, exactly that. You don't need the parenthesis thought (won't hurt, but won't help either)

Answer (score 2):

First check if the form has been submitted:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" " method="post">
<input name="username" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary"/><br/>
</form>

if($_POST['Submit'] == "Upload")
{

    $username = $_POST['username'];

}
```

Comment: I think I was misunderstood... the client can enter any value they like so it has to be dynamic. Thanks.

Comment: if you need input names to be variables in php (which is weird and vulnerable), check out `register_globals` directive.