# Connecting commenter with comment. Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cmmntr_id' cannot be null'

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

Goal is to link unique commenter to their comment. Can I capture the mmbrname using the session variable? The following gives the error:

NOTE: When field is not hidden, the mmbrname does appear but fails to upload the name (value) into the db.

HTML form:

```
<!-- BEGIN: cmmntr_id INSERT into db -->
    <input class="hidden" type="text" name="cmmntr_id" id"cmmntr_id" value="<?= htmlentities($_SESSION['mmbrname']); ?>" />
<!-- END: cmmntr_id INSERT into db -->
```

INSERT statement:

```
try {
$sql = "INSERT INTO folk_cmmnts (cmmntr_id, cmmnts, img, sng, vid)
        VALUES (:cmmntr_id, :cmmnts, :img, :sng, :vid)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cmmntr_id', $cmmntr_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cmmnts', $cmmnts);
        $stmt->bindParam(':img', $img);
        $stmt->bindParam(':sng', $sng);
        $stmt->bindParam(':vid', $vid);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're missing an `=` in `id"cmmntr_id"` - might mess up HTML parsing. Where are you initializing `$cmmntr_id`?

Comment: Thanks Kenney. I'm a beginner and have managed to struggle through with some success. Me and Lynda.com. This is the first iteration of  id="cmmntr_id". Much of what I've done so far has been via shotgun approach. I place the cmmntr_id there in case I may need to tie together the replies in some way. As I stated above ... I'm a beginner. !-)

Comment: Short answer: yes, you can. Use the same `$_SESSION['mmbrname']` instead of `$cmmntr_id` - if that's what you're intending. If you are also asking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569971/how-can-i-get-a-php-value-from-an-html-form), you'd use `$cmmnts = $_POST['cmmnts']` etc. A [search like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+forms?sort=votes&pageSize=15) or [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+forms+postgresql) should get you going.

Comment: Thanks Kenney. I managed to figure how to work the code successfully with your encouragement. You let me know, I was on the right track. The code on the form worked as stated above. I had to align the authenticate.php on the same page as the process.php in the form action call, then used the $mmbr_pstng variable in the $stmt. This variable connected to the $_SESSION. Works!

Onto the next series of issues, such as why I have no conflicts on one form which shares the same page, and a ton on the other form with practically identical code. Sigh. Texts uploaded.

Comment: What's often the case is that `$_POST['foo']` is used in the code without a form being submitted; the value is then not present. If so, you would `if ( isset( $_POST['name-of-submit-button'] ) ...`. What's also handy is to add `error_reporting( E_ALL ); init_set( 'display_errors', 'on' );` to the top of the script. We're happy to help you fix the remaining conflicts if you add some more code to the question, preferably enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Good morning Kenney. I've managed to fix one form for uploading events including capturing $mmbr_pstng, same as $cmmntr_id, and uploading mp3, img, and vid ... although, I continue to struggle with comments, which resides on same page. I have successfully captured $cmmntr_id, but this form gives me undefined index errors related to the img, vid, and sng files being uploaded, the code is almost identical to the code used in the event form.  --- I do have display all errors in my php.ini file turned on. Is this the same? --- I have issues with uploading files, I can't select one, has to be all.

Comment: Can't insert my code here. Too many characters. Kenny, because the code works on one form but not on the other is truly a challenge for this older brain. I'd be glad to take you up on the offer. Just don't know how to continue this thread without opening a new question. --- I have opened a new question with a similar issue related to a preference form and how to capture the mmbrname to id the row contents for potential updating. All standard kinds of stuff.

Comment: File uploads are handled differently - [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). So you have 3 kinds of input: `$_POST` for the `<form method='post'>`, `$_SESSION` for the authenticated user id, and `$_FILES` for file uploads. I'll craft an answer soon to show you the approach.